# SQL's to_date formatting not being displayed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset, jodatime

I have the below SQL query

```
select to_date(start_date, 'dd-Mon-yy') AS start_date FROM table
```

I also have the below ResultSet objects (rs)

```
rs.getDate("start_date")
```

When I run the query in SQL developer directly against the database (Oracle) the format is returned as expected (`08-AUG-12`), but when I run the query in my Java app using JDBC it prints out as `2012-08-08`.

Am I getting the format the correct way? Should I just select on the column (date datatype) and then format via JodaTime's DateTimeFormatter? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The same thing happens when I convert from java.sql.Date to java.util.Date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database format is not taken in consideration when you are dealing with a `Date` object in Java. If you want to match exactly the format that you have on your function, you can use `TO_CHAR`, and fetch the column as a `String`.

Alternatively, you keep fetching the column as `Date`, and then format it accordingly with `DateTimeFormatter`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

you are simply converting to a date here... you probably want to be converting to a string for output.

```
TO_CHAR( mydate, 'mm-dd-yyyy' )
```